# How can I create a simple window using WLMUser.framework bundled in Word for Mac?

Tags: c, macos, winapi

It seems that Microsoft has implemented a subset of WinAPI on macOS platform and it was shipped with Office for Mac.

So I created a header which contains some APIs existed in those frameworks.

```c
#ifndef wlmuser_h
#define wlmuser_h

#include <stdint.h>

typedef unsigned short ATOM;
typedef unsigned int UINT;
typedef unsigned long LONG_PTR;
typedef unsigned long UINT_PTR;
typedef LONG_PTR LRESULT;
typedef UINT_PTR WPARAM;
typedef LONG_PTR LPARAM;
typedef void * HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HINSTANCE;
typedef HANDLE HICON;
typedef HANDLE HCURSOR;
typedef HANDLE HBRUSH;
typedef HANDLE HMODULE;
typedef HANDLE HWND;
typedef char * LPSTR;
typedef const char * LPCSTR;
typedef wchar_t * LPWSTR;
typedef const wchar_t * LPCWSTR;

typedef LRESULT (*WNDPROC) (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int MessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);

HMODULE GetModuleHandleA(LPCSTR lpModuleName);

typedef struct tagWNDCLASSA {
    UINT        style;
    WNDPROC     lpfnWndProc;
    int         cbClsExtra;
    int         cbWndExtra;
    HINSTANCE   hInstance;
    HICON       hIcon;
    HCURSOR     hCursor;
    HBRUSH      hbrBackground;
    LPCSTR      lpszMenuName;
    LPCSTR      lpszClassName;
} WNDCLASSA;

ATOM RegisterClassA(const WNDCLASSA *lpWndClass);

#endif /* wlmuser_h */
```

Then I wrote a small piece of code to verify if it was worked.

```c
#include "wlmuser.h"

LRESULT WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int main(void) {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Native WinAPI on Macintosh!!!", "Some title here.", 0 /* MB_OK */);
    
    HMODULE hInstance = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);
    
    const char CLASS_NAME[] = "Sample Window Class";
    
    WNDCLASSA wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    
    RegisterClassA(&wc);
    
    return 0;
}

LRESULT WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, the `MessageBoxA` does work well, but the program crashed on the line

```c
RegisterClassA(&wc);
```

I have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: People use the term *"crash"* to mean just about anything. What's the exact observed behavior?

Comment: @IInspectable `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` inside `RegisterClassA `